# Assert Violation: c() 2nd argument Ctor must be a function

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am new at Salesforce I am doing a LWC technology that I barely know. The logic is the next one: When the user clicks on Si in the radio button this displays me an other field. So when I click on Si this throws me the next Error: Assert Violation: c() 2nd argument Ctor must be a function.
I am doing the next LWC:

app.html:

```
<template>
<lightning-card title="MiEntregable" icon-name="standard:record">
   <div class="slds-var-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-input label="Identificador de mi entregable" disabled value={accountId}></lightning-input>
        <lightning-input label="Nombre de mi entregable" onchange={handleNameChange} class="slds-var-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
                  <lightning-input label="Nombre del estudiante" onchange={handleNameChange} class="slds-var-m-bottom_x-small"></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-radio-group name="¿En pareja?"
                                                                        label="¿Actividad en pareja?"
                                                                        options={options}
                                                                        value={selectedvalue}
                                                                        onchange={handlechange} 
                                                                        type="radio"></lightning-radio-group>
                    <template  if:true={selectedvalue}>
                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Nombre del compañero"></lightning-input-field>
                    </template>
                    <lightning-button label="Crear entregable" variant="brand" onclick={createAccount}></lightning-button>
   </div>
</lightning-card>
```

app.js:

```
    import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

    export default class App extends LightningElement {
      title = "Welcome to Lightning Web Components!";

  showFeatures = true;

  /**
   * Getter for the features property
   */
  get features() {
    return [
      {
        label: "Learn in the browser.",
        icon: "utility:edit",
      },
      {
        label: "View changes to code instantly with Live Compilation.",
        icon: "utility:refresh",
      },
      {
        label: "Style your components with SLDS.",
        icon: "utility:brush",
      },
    ];
  }


    // Select option1 by default
    value = '';
    //Display the radio button with its values
    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Si', value: 'option1' },
            { label: 'No', value: 'option2' },
        ];
    }
    //handle event when option1 is selected displays the field Nombre del compañero
    @track selectedvalue = false;
    handlechange(event){
      const selectedoption = event.detail.value;
      if(selectedoption == 'option1'){
        this.selectedvalue = true;
      }else{
        this.selectedvalue = false;
      }
    }

}
```

app.css

```
    h1 {
    color: rgb(0, 112, 210);
}
p {
    font-family: 'Salesforce Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: rgb(62, 62, 60);
}
.app {
    background-color: #fafaf9;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.border{
    border-color: red;
}
```

index.stories.js

```
import "@lwc/synthetic-shadow";
import "https://unpkg.com/@salesforce-ux/design-system@2.13.1/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.min.css";
import { createElement } from "lwc";
import App from "./app";

export const story = () => createElement("c-app", { is: App });
```

When I try to test in Studio webComponents.dev
How can I solve this? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when an unsupported component is encountered. The error is complaining about `lightning-input-field`, which is not part of the npm `lightning-base-components`. You can see the full list of supported elements [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-base-components).

The unsupported element list includes:

> lightning-input-rich-text
>
> lightning-file-upload
>
> lightning-record-edit-form
>
> lightning-record-view-form
>
> lightning-record-form
>
> lightning-input-field
>
> lightning-output-field
>
> lightning-map

These can't be supported because they rely on Salesforce data/connectivity.